# Why was this mod-flag on a repost declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, plagiarism

I custom mod-flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126488) answer (because the OP had reposted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126432)) with the following text:

> Possible plagiarism of another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126432, as can be seen here https://copypastor.sobotics.org/posts/1412

My flag was declined, however, with the message:

> It's not plagiarism, it's a repost, by the same author.

The answer has since been deleted.

Can the mod who declined the flag explain me why does the difference between 'repost' and 'plagiarism' affect the flag's state?

Comment: I'm not the mod who declined the flag, so I guess you won't accept an official answer from me, but I can explain the reason for the decline. One cannot plagiarize themselves; plagiarism is copying someone else's work and claiming it as your own without giving the original author credit. If someone is just reposting their own answer, that isn't plagiarism, since there's no one else from which they are robbing credit. Your flag was making an incorrect claim, so it was declined. However, the answer was still not serving any purpose, so it was deleted.

Comment: plagiarism is posting someone else content as if it is your own. Copying an answer you wrote yourself is a re-post. Re-posts do get an automatic mod-flag but if you spot them you can raise a custom flag as well. I think those re-post flags should be marked helpful but Martijn has to explain why he didn't in this case. Or listen to what Cody says ...

Comment: I don't think mods can attach a message to a flag unless they decline it, so maybe even though your flag was partially correct (the reposted answer should have been deleted) the mod wanted to draw your attention to the fact that it isn't actually plagiarism.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery as far as I remember - mods can approve a flag with a custom message. (There's just less reason to do so than when declining...)

Comment: @CodyGray Actually, [Self-Plagiarism is a thing](https://unicheck.com/blog/dangers-of-self-plagiarism/). When you quote another work, even if you're the author of both, you should still indicate the source of the quote. Of course, it's not as much as an ethical dilemma as it is a technical one since you're not really hurting anyone, so it makes sense that the mechanics of how we treat them here are softer than the harsh penalty of normal (not self) plagiarism.

Comment: That’s not actually plagiarism, @Davy, that’s failure to comply with the spirit of an academic assignment.

Comment: @CodyGray That's just a [word-thinking argument](https://www.scottadamssays.com/2016/12/21/how-to-be-unpersuasive/#word-thinking) (placing a new label on something instead of giving a reason for why the original was not accurate, or arguing over the definition of a term). Like I said, they're not the same degree and don't deserve the same penalty. Plus the source I referenced highlights three common occurrences of self-plagiarism, and academic assignments was just one example that most people could relate to. To Yivi, Feel free to call my interpretation insane, it's well established.